# Centering and filling the page with bootstrap grid and ng-repeat elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have several elements I want to display on a page, and I am using Angular's ng-repeat to do it. I want to display it by having a 3x3 column, so I am using Bootstrap's col-md-4. My HTML is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="resourcesController">
    <div class="main-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="resources">
                <div ng-repeat="org in orgs" class="col-md-4">
                    <a href={{org.url}} target="_blank"><img src={{org.icon}}></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the elements are appearing like so:

[image: my webpage]

How can I center the elements and spread them over evenly across the page while using ng-repeat? Thank you!

Comment: It would also help if you provided us with a version of the code ( as a minimum in the question) or attached as link or a fiddle.

Comment: use centering css for content of each column

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that it is not enough to use only one ng-repeat.
Instead, you could separate your `orgs` array into an array of arrays representing rows of columns.

Then you could modify the code similarly to below (making it easier to apply the grid format you want):

```
  <div ng-repeat="orgRow in orgRows" class="rowClass">
  <div ng-repeat="orgElement in orgRow "class="columnClass" >
    <a href={{orgElement.url}} target="_blank"><img src={{org.icon}}></a>
  </div>          
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple bootstrap helper class `text-center` should do most of it for you

```
<div ng-repeat="org in orgs" class="col-md-4 text-center">
```

In addition could add class to the `<a>` tags and:

```
a.content-class{display:block; text-align:center}
```